# React Native Google Pay payment error [OR_BIBED_01]

Tags: android, react-native, google-pay

I am getting following error when I am paying for google products from testing mode few times , I couldn't find why it is showing but most of times not showing error and going to payment screen.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Using @stripe/stripe-react-native library.

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to invoke the stripe/stripe-react-native library? `OR_BIBED_01` usually relates to test/prod misconfiguration. So for example: You are using the prod environment with test data.

Answer (score 1):

The above issue could be due to config params , like SupportedNetworks passed while invoking the request, Passing the environment as PROD in test, and even the other configs params in the Google pay initiation call

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i'm trying to get google pay working in TEST environment with no success. The difference here is that i bridged the native google pay with react native but i'm getting the same error. Below is my request body.

```
{
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "apiVersionMinor": 0,
  "allowedPaymentMethods": [
    {
      "type": "CARD",
      "parameters": {
        "allowedAuthMethods": [
          "PAN_ONLY",
          "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"
        ],
        "allowedCardNetworks": [
          "AMEX",
          "DISCOVER",
          "INTERAC",
          "JCB",
          "MASTERCARD",
          "VISA"
        ]
      },
      "tokenizationSpecification": {
        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
        "parameters": {
          "gateway": "example",
          "gatewayMerchantId": "exampleGatewayMerchantId"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "transactionInfo": {
    "totalPrice": "1.50",
    "totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
    "countryCode": "ARE",
    "currencyCode": "AED",
    "checkoutOption": "COMPLETE_IMMEDIATE_PURCHASE"
  },
  "merchantInfo": {
    "merchantName": "Dalma Mall"
  }
}
```